# PHP and FBML module?

Tags: facebook

Hi I am trying create a section on my FB page which uses PHP and JavaScript to take a date stored in a database on another server and then use JS to make a countdown script - all inside a FB profile.

Would I be able to use the FBML html module, or will I have to create a full fledged FB Application and have that interact with my FB Page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd do this with FBML, but it'd be extremely easy to build this with a Page Tab App. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ for more info.